# Moving text at the end of DateTime

Tags: c#, combobox, dropdown

I'm having an issue with formatting text within `dropdown` boxes. I'm currently generating fields in a `time format` with AM/PM at the end. I have two `dropdown`, one for Hours and one for Minutes. I can add the AM/PM to the hours column but I'm not able to move that "AM/PM" to show after the minutes column. I'd prefer to not use one dropdown to show all of the time options.

Ultimately the goal is to have a user select the time from the `Hours` and `Minutes` column and when they click the button at the far right it puts some text to their clipboard.

[image: Dropdown Example]

```
  var hours = Enumerable.Range(00, 24).Select(i => (DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(i)).ToString("hhtt"));
        foreach (var h in hours)
        {
            combo_fromhoursMonday.Items.Add(h);
            combo_fromhoursTuesday.Items.Add(h);
            combo_fromhoursWednesday.Items.Add(h);
            combo_fromhoursThursday.Items.Add(h);
            combo_fromhoursFriday.Items.Add(h);
            combo_fromhoursSaturday.Items.Add(h);
            combo_fromhoursSunday.Items.Add(h);
        }
        var minutes = Enumerable.Range(00, 4).Select(i => (DateTime.MinValue.AddMinutes(i * 15)).ToString("mm"));
        foreach (var m in minutes)
        {
            combo_fromminutesMonday.Items.Add(m);
            combo_fromminutesTuesday.Items.Add(m);
            combo_fromminutesWednesday.Items.Add(m);
            combo_fromminutesThursday.Items.Add(m);
            combo_fromminutesFriday.Items.Add(m);
            combo_fromminutesSaturday.Items.Add(m);
            combo_fromminutesSunday.Items.Add(m);
        }
```

Edit: If I choose 03PM from the hours column and 00 from the Minutes column then click the Monday button I'm left with the following text on my clipboard.

Time Selected: 03PM00 to 04PM15

Example selected dropdowns: [image]

I'm needing to move that PM text to the end of the minutes column.

Here is the code from the buttonclick event

```
        private void buttonMonday_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText("On-call " + combo_fromhoursMonday.SelectedItem.ToString() + combo_fromminutesMonday.SelectedItem.ToString() + " to " 
            + combo_tohoursMonday.SelectedItem.ToString() + combo_tominutesMonday.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: This part doesn't make sense, explain further: `"but I'm not able to move that "AM/PM" to show after the minutes column"`

Comment: add another dropdown for AM or PM selection. that would be simple. I hope. not clear about your requirement

Comment: I guess the relevant code is in the button click handler for "Monday" which we can't see because you haven't posted the code

Answer (score 0):

I added a third 'dropdown' for the AM/PM column.